# Delete background of an image and add it without background

Tags: background, paint.net

How can I delete the background of an image and add it to layer without background? What I can do so far is delete background, but when I add the image on which background was deleted the program treats it as though there is a background. I am stuck.
Here is an image before deleting background:
[image]

Here is an image after I deleted background on it:
[image]

Here is what I get when try to add the picture without background to another picture:
[image]

As you can see the picture without background still has background which goes over other pictures. I tried to use Magic Wand for selected rectangle with the image, but it selects entire layer.

Answer (score 0):

Go like this on the sword picture:

```
ctrl + a
ctrl + c
```

Then open a new layer in the Kisame picture (layer has to be above) and do:

```
ctrl + v
```

Please note that if you save this picture for example as `.jpg` , the transparent parts will be filled with black. If you want to keep the transparent parts, save it as `.png`. Saving the picture will automatically merge all layers